# Azure remote debugging with VS 2015 not connecting

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-debugger

I have just upgraded to VS2015 and when I try to connect the Remote Debugger to an Azure web app, I get this error:

> The following error occurred while launching remote debugging:  Unable
> to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named
> 'xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net'.  The remote debugger is older than this
> version of Visual Studio 2015, and Visual Studio is no longer
> compatible with it. Please upgrade your remote debugger to match
> Visual Studio.

I have checked the Azure Web App settings and Remote Debugging is on, and VS2015 is selected as the remote debugger.

The Azure App Service Support - Event Viewer is reporting this warning

> Msvsmon was unable to start a server named '127.0.0.1:50245'. The
> following error occurred: An instance of the remote debugger is
> already running on this computer, or another process is already bound
> to the specified TCP/IP port. View Msvsmon's help for more
> information. 08005E80

I guess this is problem but how do I resolve it?

Comment: Not sure it makes a difference, but did you deploy the app with Visual Studio 2015? Did you deploy a debug build?

Comment: Yes have deployed with VS2015 debug build

Comment: Also recreated the Azure Web Site from scratch, deployed debug build, and can now connect remote debugger, but for some reason I don't get the menu option to Start Profiling.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, anyone with a solution? :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue, this is a very crippling issue and its very disappointing to see no response from someone from Azure team with some help on how to resolve this, here I am 3 years later still having this issue and no replies here still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726954/login-failure-remote-debugging-asp-net-webapi-service-hosted-as-an-azure-app-ser

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you deploy a 'DEBUG' build of your application to Azure App Service from Visual Studio 2015. If the debugger still won't connect, you could try making sure to have the latest updates installed to your local Visual Studio 2015, then try it again.