# Login failure remote debugging ASP.NET WebAPI service hosted as an Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to remote debug my ASP.NET WebAPI web-service, it is hosted in Azure as an App Service, I am trying to attach to it from Visual Studio 2015 Debug menu, I get this error, I know my login credentials are correct, I freely log into the Azure Portal with the same credentials.

Error Message: `Visual Studio was unable to create a secure connection to` `Authentication failed`

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your screenshot, it seems that you are using the Azure account for authentication.

It seems that we need to use the azure deployment user and password. We could get the user and password for Azure publish profile. We could get the Azure publish profile from Azure Portal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is the user I need to use, that got me past the error I asked about.

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem. I downloaded the profile, and tried to use the username (like "$AppName") and password without luck. After a while I found another username (like "Appname\$Appname") in the publish profile (FTP publish method) with the same password; this one did work after all